# ESP32 as main controller and ESP8266 as client

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I am making a project in which I want to use ESP32 as the main controller and ESP8266 as client(for collecting data from the sensors).

I want to use the MQTT protocol and send all the data to the Ubidots platform as shown in the attached diagram.
ESP32 and ESP8266 will be connected to Mobile Hotspot.

My question is whether ESP32 as the main controller will work in **station mode** and ESP8266 in **AP mode** or opposite? Or in which they can work? (It is a kind of basic question)

Because I have to specify the mode in the code in Arduino IDE.

[Like this I want my system to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgFXs.jpg)

Comment: if they connect to hotspot, both are STA

Answer (score 0):

According to what you described, you're right. The station would be the ESP32, and your APs the multiple ESP8266 configured; the ESP32 will serve you as a gateway and the ESP8266 as nodes.

[This guide](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-client-server-wi-fi/) can serve as a reference for your project. The only thing you must replace is the WiFi library required by the ESP8266 along with the necessary configurations.

Once you have established the communication between the devices, you can refer to [this guide](https://help.ubidots.com/en/articles/748067-connect-an-esp32-devkitc-to-ubidots-over-mqtt) to send your data from your ESP32 to [Ubidots](https://ubidots.com/) over MQTT.

Comment: Thanks for the response and references. These references are very helpful. In the above comment by respected member @Juraj, if both (ESP32 & ESP8266) are connected to hotspot than both will be in Station mode. I am confused with the Station mode and Access point mode.